# Как организовать отдачу кэша с помощью mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

При открытии урла http://sub.domain.com/?id=linux_book проверяем наличие файла www/sub.domain.com/cache/linux_book

Если есть - отдавать сразу его, если нет - заворачивать на www/index.php

Под www подразумевается document root.

Заранее спасибо. Приспичило для одной поделки в кратчайшие сроки сделать простейший кеш (использовал бы nginx, но нет возможности в данном случае).